# PHP : How do I get the content in an html tag?

Tags: php, html, web-scraping

I am trying to get data by scraping a website, and for this I need to get the content of a html tag.

This is my code at the moment

```
<?php

require('simple_html_dom.php');

// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('https://www.tripadvisor.fr/Restaurants-g187147-c20-Paris_Ile_de_France.html');

// creating an array of elements
$restos = [];

$i = 1;
foreach ($html->find('div.restaurants-list-List__wrapper--3PzDL') as $resto) {
        if ($i > 10) {
                break;
        }
        // Find item link element
        $restoDetails = $resto->find('a.restaurants-list-ListCell__restaurantName--2aSdo', 0);
        // get title attribute
        $restoName = $restoDetails->target;
        // get href attribute
        $restoUrl = 'https://tripadvisor.fr' . $restoDetails->href;

        // push to a list of restaurants
        $restos[] = [
                'name' => $restoName,
                'url' => $restoUrl
        ];

        $i++;
}
var_dump($restos);


?>
```

The issue that I have is that the "target" tag is like this

```
<a> ... target = "_blank"> Epicure</a>
```

So my feature $restoName is "_blank", but I would like to get "Epicure" instead.
I've looked around for solutions but none of them seem to solve this problem..

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Try `$restoDetais->plaintext`

Comment: Oh it worked ! Thanks a lot !

I just have a question regarding this solution, what if I had several tags with contents (it's not the case here but what if), how would it know that I'm aiming for the "target" content ? and not another tag ?
Like if I had target = "_blank" > text1 otherTag = "_blank2" > text2 ?

Comment: Not sure I follow. `->plaintext` will get the contents of a tag whereas `->target` or `->href` for example will get the attribute with that name.

Comment: But the attribute with the name target in my case is   "_blank" ```, but the info that I was trying to get was ```target = "_blank" > info``` , it's the content of the tag, but if I had a tag that looked like this  ```target = "_blank" > info1  href = "_self" > info2``` ? Then I wonder what  ```-> plaintext ``` would return ?